# Fourier series and regular distribution

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, schwartz-distributions

Assume you have a distribution $K$ on $\mathbb{T}$, the torus, such that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |K(e_n)|^2$ is finite, where $e_n := e^{in\cdot}$ are the Fourier basis. Does this imply that the distribution is regular, i.e. $K(g)= \int_{\mathbb{T}} fg$ for some $f \in L^2$?

Intuitively, something like this should hold as many examples do indicate, but I currently just can't find a way to show this.

Comment: What about comparing $K$ with $f:=\sum K(e_n) e_n$?

Comment: $\langle K,\varphi \rangle$ is well-defined for $\varphi \in  C^\infty(\mathbb{T})$. Clearly, $\varphi = \sum_n \langle \varphi, e_n \rangle e_n$ (where $e_n$ have been normalized). Hence $\langle K,\varphi \rangle = \sum_n \langle K,e_n \rangle  \langle \varphi,e_n \rangle $ and $K = \sum_n \langle K,e_n \rangle e_n$ in the sense of distributions. What I'm not sure about is that maybe I should regularize the last series, for example $K = \lim_{r \to 1^-} \sum_n r^{|n|} \langle K,e_n \rangle e_n $

Comment: @user1952009: No. The series defining $K$ converges in $L^2$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling of course, but I meant in the general case of a distribution on the torus